# I asked 4 questions on Super User and now I am banned

Tags: support, ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Can I please get un-banned at Super User? I've only asked 4 questions, and now I'm banned.

I read the guide ([What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)), and I understand that I made a mistake.

I thought Super User was for any computer related questions.

My profile is: https://superuser.com/users/29475/bodacydo

I will be more careful when asking questions from now on.

Comment: Please read the guide a bit more carefully, it clearly tells you that the ban is automatic and there's nothing any one of us can do. It's completely up to you, fix your previous questions, contribute some great answers.

Comment: Should I delete all my questions that were closed? There is not much to fix as they're closed...

Comment: I'll contribute some great answers, thanks.

Comment: Deleted questions _still_ count towards the ban. And you can still edit closed questions...

Comment: Took a quick look at your questions, please stop adding stuff like "Thanks, Boda Cydo.", your avatar is under every post you make, we know who you are, and you can thank good answers by upvoting them and great answers by marking them as accepted. Your questions don't seem _that_ bad, but please read Super User's FAQ thoroughly (twice) to see what questions they welcome and what they could live without.

Comment: The key is to do the same thing you would in any other social situation. Look around the room and see what other people are doing. If they're not adding signatures, then ask yourself *why*. Things are a bit different on Stack Exchange than traditional forums, but if you spend some time here it will start to click. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4):

If it helps, it doesn't look like you're currently question-blocked.

You're on the edge, though. I suggest editing your existing posts to make them better and keeping the tips from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) and the [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) in mind when posting future questions. (And, of course, the [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq).)

Comment: It helps. Thanks Anna. I'll edit my posts and contribute great answers!